# Insertion the same value many times in extendable hashing

Tags: database, hash

When inserting extendable hashing as the following keys when the same key value is added again and again would it be added to the hashing bucket? or does it eliminate the duplicate values? For an example there below, 11 is added for 2 times.

11,33,35,78,12,56,34,11,22,99

Answer (score 1):

A key can only be entered once.

What may get chained are *different* keys if they happen to collide on their hash values.

So if the "11" in your example refers to the key value itself, it will be discarded (or replace the existing entry, or raise an exception). If it refers to the hash value of a key value and the two key values are different (just happen to hash to 11 both), then you'll get both entries.

Comment: What if two keys happen to share the exact same hash and an overflow happens when you insert one of them? Wouldn't there be an infinite loop of directory expansion?